# $(document.documentElement) target specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function like this:

```
jQuery(document.documentElement).on('click touch', function(e) {
    // check if $(e.target) matches with $('ul#menu-navigation > li.menu-item')
    // or any child elements within this particular div.
});
```

How do I make an **if** statement checking if `e.target` matches with `$('ul#menu-navigation > li.menu-item')` or any child elements within **this** particular div.

For example, something like:

```
if ( $(e.target) == $('ul#menu-navigation > li.menu-item') ) {
    // user clicked on this div or any child divs within this element
} else {
    // user clicked anywhere outside of this div
}
```

Comment: why aren't you just attaching the click event to that one element?

Comment: Are you looking for the [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method?

Comment: Are you looking for event delegation? `jQuery(document.documentElement).on('click touch', '#menu-navigation > .menu-item', function (e) { … })`?

Comment: What do you mean by _or any child elements within this particular div_? I see no div element in there!

Comment: FYI: `jQuery(document.documentElement)` can be replaced with: `$(document)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to start at target and look up

```
jQuery(document).on('click touch', function(e) {
    if($(e.target).closest('ul#menu-navigation > li.menu-item').length){
      // is within a menu item
    }   
});
```

Comment: This is really a clever solution!

Comment: This is lovely. Thank you! Although shouldn't it be `.length()`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`jQuery.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) like this:

```
if ( $(e.target).is('ul#menu-navigation *') ) {
    // user clicked on this div or any child divs within this element
} else {
    // user clicked anywhere outside of this div
}
```

And if you want to include only `ul#menu-navigation > li.menu-item` and children of `li.menu-item` use this selector: `'ul#menu-navigation > li.menu-item, ul#menu-navigation > li.menu-item *'`

Comment: But will this *if* statement work if the user clicks on a child element like for example: `ul#menu-navigation > li.menu-item > .random-child`?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson then don't use direct children notation. See the update! Now it works for any element in the descendants!

Comment: @charlietfl which one are you talking about? This one `'ul#menu-navigation *'` or this one `'ul#menu-navigation > li.menu-item, ul#menu-navigation > li.menu-item *'`?

Answer (score 1):

Try use `if ($(e.target).is('ul#menu-navigation > li.menu-item'))`

This will ask if the element match.

```js
jQuery(document.documentElement).on('click touch', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is('ul#menu-navigation > li.menu-item')) {
    // user clicked on this div or any child divs within this element
    alert("I clicked on LI")
  } else {
    // user clicked anywhere outside of this div
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-navigation">
  <li class="menu-item">Home</li>
  <li class="menu-item">About</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But will this *if* statement work if the user clicks on a child element like for example: `ul#menu-navigation > li.menu-item > .random-child`?

Answer (score 0):

I can not really understood the benefit of this function. 
I can imagine you can resolve the problem by using `e.currentTarget` instead of `e.target`, when you dont bind the event to `document.documentElement`. Bind it to your target, in this case I think it should be `$('ul#menu-navigation > li.menu-item')`

```
$('ul#menu-navigation > li.menu-item').on('click', function (event) {
    var $target = $(event.currentTarget);
})
```

With this solution, you know it is the element what you want and you reduce the overhead, because you dont listen to every klick somewhere in your document.